Icon notifications not updating in Ubuntu 24.04
As per the screenshot attached, notifications on certain applications (this is happening with slack as well) are not being processed by Ubuntu 24.04. Any thoughts on how to address this? I'd be happy to give more details about anything relevant about my system/specs.


After some digging, I found out why. Currently, I have "3" notifications in my file explorer's icon in the task bar which happen to be ones I did not clear from the notification panel (on top, by clicking on the calendar), like so:

Now, let's remove two notifications:

And finally:


Thanks for the clarification. Glad it's not some bug. This problem was driving me nuts!
